# Flutter search nested list of objects

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I am building a Flutter app for selling alcohol/bottle delivery service. I'm having issues trying to search a beverage in the search bar. I have put the bottles in a nested list because the bottles have different categories. When I try to search for a bottle nothing actually comes up in the search bar. I guess I have something to fix in my code. I define the nested list categories. Then I access the bottle object using the method getBottle() method and return a list of bottle objects which is assigned to a new list called allBottles. The retrieved bottle object is then used in a search query. However I get nothing when I type in the searchbar. Can anyone please assist. Below is my code

This image shows the search bar with the hintext

[image]

This image shows the search bar with the searched text

[image]

```
class ProductProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final List<BottleCategory> categories = [
    BottleCategory(categoryNo: 1, bottleType: 'Beers', bottleList: [
      Bottle(
          id: 'AMST',
          bottleName: 'Amstel Lager',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/AmstelLager.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'BLKL',
          bottleName: 'Black Label',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/BlackLabel.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'CSTL',
          bottleName: 'Castle Lite',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/CastleLite.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'CRNE',
          bottleName: 'Corona Extra',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/CoronaExtra.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'HNKN',
          bottleName: 'Heineken',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/HeinekenOriginalBottle.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'WDHK',
          bottleName: 'Windhoek Draught',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/WindhoekDraught.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
    ]),
    BottleCategory(categoryNo: 2, bottleType: 'Brandy', bottleList: [
      Bottle(
          id: 'KLPB',
          bottleName: 'Klipdrift Brandy',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/KlipdriftBrandy.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'KWV3',
          bottleName: 'Kwv Brandy 3 years',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/KwvBrandy3years.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
    ]),
    BottleCategory(categoryNo: 3, bottleType: 'Ciders', bottleList: [
      Bottle(
          id: 'BLGT',
          bottleName: 'Belgravia Gin and Tonic',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/BelgraviaGinAndTonic.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'BRNB',
          bottleName: 'Bernini Blush',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/BerniniBlush.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'BRTF',
          bottleName: 'Brutal Fruit',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/BrutalFruit.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'FLYF',
          bottleName: 'Flying Fish',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/FlyingFish.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'HNTD',
          bottleName: 'Hunters Dry',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/HuntersDry.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'HNTG',
          bottleName: 'Hunters Gold',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/HuntersGold.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'ICET',
          bottleName: 'Ice Tropez',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/IceTropez.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'RDSB',
          bottleName: 'Red Square Blue Ice',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/RedSquareBlueIce.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'SRMG',
          bottleName: 'Smirnoff Guarana',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/SmirnoffGuarana.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'SRMS',
          bottleName: 'Smirnoff Storm',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/SmirnoffStorm.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'STRB',
          bottleName: 'Strong bow',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/Strongbow.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
    ]),
    BottleCategory(categoryNo: 4, bottleType: 'Cocktails', bottleList: [
      Bottle(
          id: '',
          bottleName: 'Heineken',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/HeinekenOriginalBottle.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: '',
          bottleName: 'Heineken',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/HeinekenOriginalBottle.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: '',
          bottleName: 'Heineken',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/HeinekenOriginalBottle.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: '',
          bottleName: 'Heineken',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/HeinekenOriginalBottle.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
    ]),
    BottleCategory(categoryNo: 5, bottleType: 'Cognac', bottleList: [
      Bottle(
          id: 'CRVV',
          bottleName: 'Courvoisier VS',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/CourvoisierVS.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'HNSY',
          bottleName: 'Hennesy',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/HennesyCognac.jpeg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'HNVC',
          bottleName: 'Honor VS Cognac',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/HonorVSCognac.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'RMVS',
          bottleName: 'Remy Martin VSOP Cognac',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/RemyMartinVSOPCognac.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
    ]),
    BottleCategory(categoryNo: 6, bottleType: 'Dry Red Wine', bottleList: [
      Bottle(
          id: '',
          bottleName: 'Heineken',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/HeinekenOriginalBottle.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: '',
          bottleName: 'Heineken',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/HeinekenOriginalBottle.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: '',
          bottleName: 'Heineken',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/HeinekenOriginalBottle.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: '',
          bottleName: 'Heineken',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/HeinekenOriginalBottle.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
    ]),
    BottleCategory(categoryNo: 7, bottleType: 'Gin', bottleList: [
      Bottle(
          id: 'BLGN',
          bottleName: 'Belgravia Gin',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/BelgraviaGin.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'BMBS',
          bottleName: 'Bombay Sapphire Gin',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/BombaySapphireGin.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'GDLG',
          bottleName: 'Gordon London Dry Gin',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/GordonLondonDryGin.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'TNGN',
          bottleName: 'Tanqueray Gin',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/TanquerayGin.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
    ]),
    BottleCategory(categoryNo: 8, bottleType: 'Liqueur', bottleList: [
      Bottle(
          id: 'AMLC',
          bottleName: 'Amarula Cream',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/AmarulaCream.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'JAGM',
          bottleName: 'Jagermeister',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/Jagermeister.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'STWL',
          bottleName: 'Strawberry Lips',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/StrawberryLips.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
    ]),
    BottleCategory(categoryNo: 9, bottleType: 'Soft Drinks', bottleList: [
      Bottle(
          id: 'APPT',
          bottleName: 'Appletiser',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/Appletiser.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'COCA',
          bottleName: 'Coca Cola',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/CocaCola.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'GRPT',
          bottleName: 'Grapetiser',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/Grapetiser.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'SPRT',
          bottleName: 'Sprite',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/Sprite.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'TNWT',
          bottleName: 'Tonic Water',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/TonicWater.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
    ]),
    BottleCategory(categoryNo: 10, bottleType: 'Sparkling', bottleList: [
      Bottle(
          id: 'ARMG',
          bottleName: 'Armand De Brignac Brut Gold',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/ArmandDeBrignacBrutGold.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'DMPL',
          bottleName: 'Dom Perignon Luminous',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/DomPerignonLuminous.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'MCBI',
          bottleName: 'Moet and Chandon Brut Imperial',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/MoetAndChandonBrutImperial.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'MCNI',
          bottleName: 'Moet and Chandon Nectar Imperial',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/MoetAndChandonNectarImperial.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'MNIR',
          bottleName: 'Moet and Chandon Nectar Imperial Rose',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/MoetAndChandonNectarImperialRose.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'VVCB',
          bottleName: 'Veuve Clicquot Brut',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/VeuveClicquotBrut.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'VVCR',
          bottleName: 'Veuve Clicquot Rich',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/VeuveClicquotRich.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00)
    ]),
    BottleCategory(categoryNo: 11, bottleType: 'Vodka', bottleList: [
      Bottle(
          id: '1818',
          bottleName: '1818 Vodka',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/1818-original.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'ABSL',
          bottleName: 'Absolut Vodka',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/AbsolutVodka.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'BLVD',
          bottleName: 'Belvedere Vodka',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/BelvedereVodka.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'CRCV',
          bottleName: 'Ciroc Vodka',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/CirocVodka.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'CRZB',
          bottleName: 'Cruz Banana',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/CruzBanana.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'CRZV',
          bottleName: 'Cruz Vintage',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/CruzVintage.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'CRZW',
          bottleName: 'Cruz Watermelon',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/CruzWatermelon.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'RDSV',
          bottleName: 'Red Square Vodka',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/RedSquareVodka.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'RUSB',
          bottleName: 'Russian Bear Vodka',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/RussianBearVodka.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: 'SKYY',
          bottleName: 'Skyy Vodka',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/SkyyVodka.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
    ]),
    BottleCategory(categoryNo: 12, bottleType: 'White Wine', bottleList: [
      Bottle(
          id: '',
          bottleName: 'Heineken',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/HeinekenOriginalBottle.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: '',
          bottleName: 'Heineken',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/HeinekenOriginalBottle.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: '',
          bottleName: 'Heineken',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/HeinekenOriginalBottle.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: '',
          bottleName: 'Heineken',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/HeinekenOriginalBottle.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
    ]),
    BottleCategory(categoryNo: 13, bottleType: 'Whiskey', bottleList: [
      Bottle(
          id: '',
          bottleName: 'Bells Scotch',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/BellsScotch.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: '',
          bottleName: 'J & B Whiskey',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/JBWhiskey.png',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: '',
          bottleName: 'Jameson',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/Jameson.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
      Bottle(
          id: '',
          bottleName: 'Johnnie Walker Black Label',
          image: 'lib/assets/images/JohnnieWalkerBlackLabel.jpg',
          time: 20,
          price: 274.00),
    ]),
  ];
  List<Bottle> getBottleItem() {
    List<Bottle> localBottles = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < categories.length; x++) {
      var currentElement = categories[x].bottleList;
      for (var y = 0; y < currentElement.length; y++) {
        var bottleElement = currentElement[y];
        localBottles.add(bottleElement);
      }
    }
    print(localBottles);
    return localBottles;
  }

  late List<Bottle> allBottles = getBottleItem();
  late List<Bottle> bottles;
  String query = " ";

  void searchBottle(String query) {
    final bottles = allBottles.where((bottle) {
      final titleLower = bottle.bottleName.toLowerCase();
      final searchLower = query.toLowerCase();

      return titleLower.contains(searchLower);
    }).toList();

    setState(() {
      this.bottles = bottles;
      this.query = query;
    });
  }

  Widget buildSearch() {
    return SearchWidget(
      text: query,
      hintText: 'Search for beverages',
      onChanged: searchBottle,
    );
  }
}
```

Code for searchWidget:

```
class SearchWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;
  final String hintText;
  const SearchWidget(
      {Key? key,
      required this.text,
      required this.onChanged,
      required this.hintText})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SearchWidget> createState() => _SearchWidgetState();
}

class _SearchWidgetState extends State<SearchWidget> {
  final controller = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: TextField(
        controller: controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            suffixIcon: widget.text.isNotEmpty
                ? GestureDetector(
                    child: const Icon(Icons.close),
                    onTap: () {
                      controller.clear();
                      widget.onChanged('');
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                    },
                  )
                : null,
            hintText: widget.hintText,
            border: InputBorder.none),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call your call onChanged, your onChanged in the TextField is not defined.

```
onChanged: widget.onChanged,
```